# There is no connection of Laravel to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, rest, laravel-8

I am making API requests from React to Laravel for user registration. This is still a test version. When requesting, I should get a response about successful registration, but I get an error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
> (Internal Server Error) message: "Database connection [moneyway] not
> configured

I used Laravel 5 and OpenServer before and everything worked fine. But after switching to Laravel 8, I ran into such a difficulty. Maybe I just forgot some detail, but I still haven't figured out what exactly.

I expected that when Laravel received JSON data, it would add a new record to the database and then return a response to the client server in the form of data that was originally sent to it.
Here is my code that I wrote:

React:

**App.js:**

```js
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Accept':'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "login": "Test_validate",
      "email": "test@mail.ru",
      "password": "password_123",
      "password_repeat": "password_123",
      "age": 19
  })
};
  fetch('http://moneywayserver/api/registration', requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Laravel:

**.env:**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=moneyway 
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

**ClientControler.php:**

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Client;
class ClientController extends Controller
{
    public function registration(Request $request){
        $new_client = new Client();
        $new_client->login = $request->{"login"};
        $new_client->email =  $request->{"email"};
        $new_client->password= $request->{"password"};
        $new_client->age= $request->{"age"};
        $new_client->save();
        return response()->json($request->all());
    }
}
```

**Model\Client.php:**

```php
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'moneyway';
    protected $table = 'users';
}
```

**database.php**

```php
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'moneyway'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Comment: There is no mysql connection named `moneyway`. Either remove `protected $connection = 'moneyway';` or create/name a connection

Comment: I didn't quite understand everything. But if I delete protected $connection = 'moneyway' then nothing has changed

Comment: The connection is named `mysql`, from `'mysql' => [...` - that's the name of the connection.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just confused. Do you mean this line here ? 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
If so, I have it written correctly

Comment: You most likely never need to change anything in `config/database.php`. Set your credentials in your `.env` file. Maybe clear config after making changes. Maybe (re)read https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database

Comment: Yes, I know, and I have never used it before, I did not climb into this file. Only when this problem came out did I have to climb in. But now I decided to put everything back and everything worked. I still didn't understand what the problem was initially. Thank you so much

Comment: The problem is that you set the connection to `moneyway` in `protected $connection = 'moneyway';`. Is there a database connection _named_ `moneyway` in your `config/database.php`? There isn't. There's `mysql`, `sqlite`, `pgsql` and `sqlsrv`.